# Can you use a php header redirect on a rtmp url?

Tags: php, url, redirect, header, rtmp

Curious, as I've been asked to do this.  I can't find any sort of protocol anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) and the `Location` header you can redirect to any URI you want.

```
header('Location: rtmp://domain/path/to/resource');
```